# Count number of columns in pyspark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 15 columns (4 categorical and the rest numeric).

I have created dummy variables for every categorical variable. Now I want to find the number of variables in my new dataframe.

I tried calculating length of `printSchema()`, but  is `NoneType`:

```
print type(df.printSchema())
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched the web?

Comment: try to check len(df.columns)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are finding it wrong way, Here is sample example for this and about printSchema:-

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1, "A", "X1"),
    (2, "B", "X2"),
    (3, "B", "X3"),
    (1, "B", "X3"),
    (2, "C", "X2"),
    (3, "C", "X2"),
    (1, "C", "X1"),
    (1, "B", "X1"),
], ["ID", "TYPE", "CODE"])


# Python 2:
print len(df.columns) #3
# Python 3
print(len(df.columns)) #3
```

`columns` provides list of all columns and we can check len. Instead `printSchema` prints schema of df which have columns and their data type, ex below:-

```
root
 |-- ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CODE: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: On pyspark console len(df.columns) is enough, not needed print.

Comment: Really hope there's an OOP solution like .length or .size, etc.

Comment: What about RDD? IF I have RDD not dataframe, how to display number of columns @Rakesh Kumar @ chuck